# How to translate Kernel space VA to PA in Linux, inside a driver code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, virtual-memory

Is it possible to do a simple page-walk translation to a Kernel-space VA, from a driver code that I write? I'm trying to use virt_to_phys(), but the translation doesn't look correct to me. Is there any other API that can do that?

Comment: What do you need the PA for?

Comment: I know the PA area where my VA supposed to map, and I want to verify that such mapping indeed exists in the kernel, and it maps to that specific area and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

`virt_to_phys()` is the correct path. Why it doesn't seem correct to you?

Take a look at [this documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/addrxlate.htmlhttp://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/addrxlate.html) that explain all the three view of a memory address and how to convert among them.